# Displaying images i upload using flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to learn flask

And i am working on uploading images using flask

my code:-

```
#main.py

import os
from app import app
import urllib.request
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if 'files[]' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
    file_names = []
    for file in files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_names.append(filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        #else:
        #   flash('Allowed image types are -> png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        #   return redirect(request.url)

    return render_template('upload.html', filenames=file_names)

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    #print('display_image filename: ' + filename)
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

upload.html :-

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask Upload Multiple Images and Display them</title>
<h2>Select multiple images to upload and display</h2>
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>

<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="true" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>

{% if filenames %}
    {% for filename in filenames %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The problem is

When i upload a image for the first time it display's, and when i upload any other image the

previous one disappears

**I want to make it display all the images which are saved in "static/uploads"**

Comment: You either have to save the list of filenames e.g. in a db or read all files from the directory they are saved.

Comment: Which one is better and safe?

Comment: Well, when you read files from a directory and show them on a web page, you have to make sure that nobody can sneak in other images /files into this directory. Other than that, I see no difference from a security perspective. Go with the way which seems easier for you to implement. If you have extremely many files, the approach with reading the files from one directory may fall behind.

Comment: Ok then i will try reading all the files from the directory